# Adding action to a next step in a js modal window

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I have a normal css/html/js modal window and it is a simple contact form. It has a send button that I'd like to turn into a Thank You modal window after the contact form is processed via php. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Replace the form by "thank you"? What is your question exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to advance to another modal window after someone clicks an input button. to give the illusion that after the user hits submit a thank you modal now shows instead of the contact form.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this on your code

```
<?php
if($send)
{
echo"<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "alert('Thank You.');";
echo "</script>";
}
else{
echo"<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "alert('Fail.');";
echo "</script>";
}
?>
```